# Copy structure of oldTable to newTable and turn off

Tags: sql

Hello this is my source:

```
SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO NEWDATABAZE.dbo.newTable
FROM OLDDATABAZE.dbo.oldTable
```

and the oldTable has identity ON and i want to turn it OFF in the newTable, but it has to be in the process of copiing of table. Not after as alter table, or delete and create etc.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is very product specific.

Comment: most probably SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for your request

**Table copy without data**

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO dbo.newtable FROM dbo.oldtable_with_identity
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.oldtable_with_identity WHERE 1 = 0
```

**Table copy with data**

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.newtable FROM dbo.oldtable_with_identity
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.oldtable_with_identity WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: This works. I just executed and seen the required o/p.